# Find edge case in palindrome logic

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I was brushing up my coding skills on CodeSignal. Initially I came up with approach1 which passes 26 out of 30 test cases, I can't see input for those failed test cases as those are hidden. Then rewrote the logic using approach2 which passed all test cases. I am scratching my head trying to find missing edge case in approach 1. Any help is appreciated.

Approach 1

```
function checkPalindrome(inputString: string): boolean {

    for(let i=0,j=inputString.length-1;i<inputString.length;i++,j--) {
        console.log(i,j,inputString.charAt(i),inputString.charAt(j));
        if(i >= j) {
            return true;
        }
        if(inputString.charAt(i) !== inputString.charAt(j)) {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Approach 2

```
function checkPalindrome(inputString: string): boolean {

    let l = 0; 
    let h = inputString.length - 1; 

    while (h > l) 
    { 
        if (inputString.charAt(l) != inputString.charAt(h)) 
        { 
            return false; 
        } 
        h=h-1;
        l=l+1;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you enter an empty string then you'll get undefined. I would say this should return true. Also, your second example isn't working

Answer (score 1):

One of the edge cases that the first approach is not covering is an empty string because `i<inputString.length` will be true on the first pass and there is no return statement after the loop, undefined is returned. The second approach is working in this case since it returns true at the end of the method.

The first approach could be fixed by changing the condition in the for loop to `i < j` and moving `return true` to the end of the method.

Comment: You are correct, @kaya3. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

- I would recommend a code clean approach, it is important not just to solve the problem, but to make sure is testable and any person can understand your code at first glance.
- This is not the only way, you could also use recursive, just remember, you don't need to loop thru the whole array.
- The code is written in Typescript, but you get the idea

```js
    isWordPalindrome101 = (palindrome: string) => {
        const test = palindrome.split('').reverse().join('');
        return palindrome === test;
    };
    
    isWordPalindromeOptimized = (word: string) => {
      let result: boolean = true;
      const wordLength = word.length;
      // we only need to loop thru half the array to verify we are good
      // remember js treats strings as arrays, so no need to convert
      for (i=0; i < wordLength /2; i++) {
        if (word[i] !== word[wordLength - 1 - i]) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
    
    let result: boolean = isWordPalindrome101('1122332211');
    console.log('Should be true:' + result);
    let result: boolean = isWordPalindrome101('test');
    console.log('Should be false:' + result);
    let result: boolean = isWordPalindromeOptimized('1122332211');
    console.log('Should be true:' + result);
    let result: boolean = isWordPalindromeOptimized('112231032211');
    console.log('Should be false:' + result);
```

Comment: In the interest of clean code, `i` should be declared, code formatting should be consistent. Also, in the optimized version, you can return false instead of breaking and remove the local

Comment: good programming practices indicate that a function should have one way in and one way out, adding multiple returns will make your code more brittle and difficult to test. The way I have my function, the result always has a value and it is clear when you get out of the loop and out of the function

Comment: forgot to mention... in typescript a basic type gets the type to infer by default if you assign a value at declaration...ex. isReal = false will assign type boolean and myNumber = 0 will assign a number type

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by basic types but yes, type inference occurs in initialization and in some cases in reassignment, type inference in happens in many other contexts as well.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: Inference isn't limited to those types